# wxWidgets: Dialog-level sizer not taking into account child ScrolledWindow's size?

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets, wxformbuilder

I have a dialog with a ScrolledWindow inside of it and a dynamic number of controls in that ScrolledWindow.

The dialog currently isn't big enough. I could manually set the width and height, but I don't know what they'll be, so I want the sizer to automatically set the size, which I believe is the way wxWidgets wants you to do it.

The ScrolledWindow has a sizer and it seems to calculate the size requirements correctly.

I've added the ScrolledWindow to the Dialog's sizer but the Dialog's sizer doesn't seem to take the ScrolledWindow's size into account for it's sizing calculations, and therefore is smaller than what the ScrolledWindow's sizer thinks it should be.

**The log below demonstrates my issue. Why does scrolling_window and scrolling_window_sizer believe their sizes to be (267, 480), but dialog_sizer thinks it can get away with (210, 63) ? Why?**

```
scrolling window best size (14, 14)
scrolling window client size (267, 480)
scrolling window effect min size (14, 14)
scrolling window min client size (-1, -1)
scrolling window min size (-1, -1)
scrolling window size (267, 480)
scrolling window virtual size (267, 480)
scrolling window best virtual size (267, 480)

scrolling_window_sizer after layout fit GetSize (267, 480)
scrolling_window_sizer after layout fit GetMinSize (267, 480)
scrolling_window_sizer after layout fit ComputeFittingClientSize(self) (267, 480)
scrolling_window_sizer after layout fit ComputeFittingWindowSize(self) (267, 480)

dialog_sizer after add scrolling window GetSize (0, 0)
dialog_sizer after add scrolling window GetMinSize (24, 24)
dialog_sizer after add scrolling window ComputeFittingClientSize(self) (24, 24)
dialog_sizer after add scrolling window ComputeFittingWindowSize(self) (24, 24)
dialog_sizer after add buttons GetSize (0, 0)
dialog_sizer after add buttons GetMinSize (210, 63)
dialog_sizer after add buttons ComputeFittingClientSize(self) (210, 63)
dialog_sizer after add buttons ComputeFittingWindowSize(self) (210, 63)

dialog best size (210, 63)
dialog client size (210, 63)
dialog effect min size (210, 63)
dialog min client size (-1, -1)
dialog min size (-1, -1)
dialog size (210, 63)
dialog virtual size (210, 63)
dialog best virtual size (210, 63)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gui/klt_gui.py", line 208, in on_cancel_button_click
    raise NotImplementedError
NotImplementedError
```

Note that this is python using wxPython, but I'm hoping this is a general issue with my usage of wxWidgets, rather than wxPython. It's a big dump of code, but hopefull it's straight forward enough to be readable. The lines that printed the log above have been marked with #!.

This line:
            # This line is a problem. Without it, I don't think the sizer will automatically adjust the window. With it, the window is tiny.
            size = dialog_sizer.Fit(self)
            self.Layout()

I added myself in order to have the sizer re-size the dialog. I'm not sure if I should do Fit pre- or post- layout, but it doesn't seem to matter because, as demonstrated by the log above, the sizer doesn't seems to take into account the buttons but not the scrolling window.

```
class AddEditCustomerDialog(wx.Dialog):
    # Based on EditCustomerTemplateFrame generated by wxFrameBuilder

    @staticmethod
    def make_section_frame(parent, parent_sizer, section_name, field_names):
        static_box = wx.StaticBox(parent, wx.ID_ANY, section_name)
        section_static_box_sizer = wx.StaticBoxSizer(static_box, wx.VERTICAL)

        flex_grid = wx.FlexGridSizer(0, 2, 5, 5)
        flex_grid.AddGrowableCol(1)
        flex_grid.SetFlexibleDirection(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        flex_grid.SetNonFlexibleGrowMode(wx.FLEX_GROWMODE_ALL)

        # do we need to keep these around? I guess for getting text etc
        text_boxes = []

        for field_name in field_names:
            label = wx.StaticText(static_box, label=field_name)
            label.Wrap(-1)
            flex_grid.Add(label, 0,
                          wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL | wx.ALIGN_RIGHT | wx.ALL,
                          5)

            # value=, validator=, name =??
            text_box = wx.TextCtrl(static_box)
            flex_grid.Add(text_box, 1, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 5)

        section_static_box_sizer.Add(flex_grid, 1, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 5)
        parent_sizer.Add(section_static_box_sizer, 1, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 5)

    def add_dialog_buttons(self, add_or_edit, parent, parent_sizer):
        # ok, cancel buttons:
        dialog_buttons = wx.StdDialogButtonSizer()

        self.save_button = wx.Button(parent, wx.ID_SAVE)
        self.cancel_button = wx.Button(parent, wx.ID_CANCEL)
        dialog_buttons.AddButton(self.save_button)
        dialog_buttons.AddButton(self.cancel_button)

        if add_or_edit == "Edit":
            self.apply_button = wx.Button(parent, wx.ID_APPLY)
            dialog_buttons.AddButton(self.apply_button)

        dialog_buttons.Realize()
        parent_sizer.Add(dialog_buttons, 0,
                         wx.ALIGN_BOTTOM | wx.ALIGN_RIGHT | wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND,
                         5)

        # Connect Events
        if add_or_edit == "Edit":
            self.apply_button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.on_apply_button_click)
        self.cancel_button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.on_cancel_button_click)
        self.save_button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.on_save_button_click)

    def __init__(self, parent, add_or_edit, config):
        assert add_or_edit in ['Add', 'Edit']

        wx.Dialog.__init__(self, parent,
                           title=add_or_edit + " Customer",
                           style=wx.DEFAULT_DIALOG_STYLE | wx.RESIZE_BORDER | wx.STAY_ON_TOP)

        self.SetSizeHintsSz(wx.DefaultSize, wx.DefaultSize)
        dialog_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        scrolling_window = wx.ScrolledWindow(self, wx.ID_ANY,
                                             wx.DefaultPosition,
                                             wx.DefaultSize,
                                             wx.HSCROLL | wx.VSCROLL)
        scrolling_window.SetScrollRate(5, 5)
        scrolling_window_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        self.make_section_frame(scrolling_window,
                                scrolling_window_sizer,
                                "LOL", ["test", "two", "three"])
        self.make_section_frame(scrolling_window,
                                scrolling_window_sizer,
                                "rofl", ["12323 3 2 1 3 21 3 2", "abc", "123"])
        self.make_section_frame(scrolling_window,
                                scrolling_window_sizer,
                                "heehhee", ["sd f  ", "fdsf dsd ", "fff"])

        scrolling_window.SetSizer(scrolling_window_sizer)
        scrolling_window.Layout()
        scrolling_window_sizer.Fit(scrolling_window)
        self.print_window_sizes(scrolling_window, "scrolling window") #!

        self.print_sizer(scrolling_window_sizer, scrolling_window,
                         "scrolling_window_sizer after layout fit") #!
        dialog_sizer.Add(scrolling_window, 1, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 5)
        self.print_sizer(dialog_sizer, self,
                         "dialog_sizer after add scrolling window") #!

        self.add_dialog_buttons(add_or_edit, self, dialog_sizer)

        self.SetSizer(dialog_sizer)

        self.print_sizer(dialog_sizer, self, "dialog_sizer after add buttons") #!


        # This line is a problem. Without it, I don't think the sizer will automatically adjust the window. With it, the window is tiny.
        size = dialog_sizer.Fit(self)

        self.Layout()
        self.Centre(wx.BOTH)
        self.print_window_sizes(self, "dialog") #!


    @staticmethod
    def print_window_sizes(scrolling_window, window_name):
        print(window_name, "best size", scrolling_window.GetBestSize())
        print(window_name, "client size", scrolling_window.GetClientSize())
        print(window_name, "effect min size", scrolling_window.GetEffectiveMinSize())
        print(window_name, "min client size", scrolling_window.GetMinClientSize())
        print(window_name, "min size", scrolling_window.GetMinSize())
        print(window_name, "size", scrolling_window.GetSize())
        print(window_name, "virtual size", scrolling_window.GetVirtualSize())
        print(window_name, "best virtual size", scrolling_window.GetBestVirtualSize())

    @staticmethod
    def print_sizer(sizer, window, sizer_name):
        print(sizer_name, "GetSize", sizer.GetSize())
        print(sizer_name, "GetMinSize", sizer.GetMinSize())
        print(sizer_name, "ComputeFittingClientSize(self)",
              sizer.ComputeFittingClientSize(window))
        print(sizer_name, "ComputeFittingWindowSize(self)",
              sizer.ComputeFittingWindowSize(window))

    def on_apply_button_click(self, event):
        event.Skip()
        raise NotImplementedError

    def on_cancel_button_click(self, event):
        event.Skip()
        raise NotImplementedError

    def on_save_button_click(self, event):
        event.Skip()
        raise NotImplementedError

app = wx.App(False)
AddEditCustomerDialog(None, "Add", None).Show(True)
app.MainLoop()
```

The code itself was mostly generated by wxFormBuilder, with modifications made by myself to make it dynamic. I'm assuming the code made by wxFormBuilder is correct. But it's here incase you think it's incorrect and doing something in the wrong order, or I've modified it badly ;)

.fbp: https://gist.github.com/Poddster/bf203294e0267d3da575f297fa5bb0a6
output code: https://gist.github.com/Poddster/684896817452c3657ad65f86263a0a7a

Comment: what version of wxPython do you use? what version of python? Which OS/toolkit?

Comment: python 2.7 :(, wxpython 3.0.2.0, `Location: /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wx-3.0-gtk2` so I guess gtk2,  on Ubuntu 16.04 and Raspbian.